# Reduce and speed up multiple regexreplace formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I use this loooooong formula to check if data in cell A33 is have regexmatch pattern from cell INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;1;1) - cell A4 - if its true, I use regexreplace patterm from cell INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;1;1) - cell B4. If its not - I go and check the next cell with regexmatch pattern - ('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;2;1) - cell A5. And do it until I find right pattern, or until reach the last cell A30 which have pattern A30 ="^.*$", B30 ="*"
Because their patterns are very diverse just it does no point in merge into one. 
Now formula work too slow for me, and it difficult for quick editing. How can I reduce and speed up the formula?

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;1;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;1;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;1;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;2;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;2;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;2;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;3;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;3;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;3;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;4;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;4;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;4;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;5;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;5;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;5;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;6;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;6;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;6;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;7;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;7;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;7;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;8;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;8;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;8;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;9;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;9;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;9;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;10;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;10;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;10;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;11;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;11;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;11;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;12;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;12;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;12;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;13;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;13;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;13;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;14;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;14;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;14;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;15;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;15;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;15;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;16;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;16;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;16;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;17;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;17;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;17;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;18;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;18;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;18;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;19;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;19;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;19;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;20;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;20;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;20;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;21;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;21;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;21;1));
IF(REGEXMATCH($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;22;1))=TRUE;REGEXREPLACE($A33;INDEX('categories'!$A$4:$A$30;22;1);INDEX('categories'!$B$4:$B$30;22;1));))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, already have an answer from gogle forum, thank to Tackky:

```
=index(filter(regexreplace($C2;$A$2:$A$19;$B$2:$B$19);regexmatch($C2;$A$2:$A$19));1)
```